# For any $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ Not extis $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with coefficients in $B$ and all roots of $P(x)$ in $A$

Tags: polynomials

> **Problem**: Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,..,a_m\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_p\}$ where $a_1,a_2,...,a_m,b_1,b_2,...,b_p \in \mathbb{R}$ Prove that ,
>   the following statements is bad :
>
> for any $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ extis $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with
>   coefficients in $B$ and all roots of $P(x)$ in $A$

*Solution

Assume for any $n$ exits $t_1,t_2,...,t_m$ are nonegative integer numbers has sum is $n$ such that: 
$P_n(x)=(x-a_1)^{t_1}(x-a_2)^{t_2}...(x-a_m)^{t_m}$ has coefficients in $B$.

Finding coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ and $x^{n-2}$ we have:

$S=-\sum_{i=1}t_ia_i^m$ and $T=\sum_{i=1}^m C_{t_1}^2a_i^2+\sum_{i<j}^mt_it_j$ and $S,T \in B$.

We have : $T=\sum_{i=1}^m C_{t_1}^2a_i^2+\sum_{i<j}^mt_it_j=\frac{1}{2}S^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m t_ia_i^2$

Let $m=\min \{a_i^2:a_i \in A\}$, then

$T \le \frac{S^2}{2}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^mt_i}{2}m^2=\frac{S^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}m^2$

Let $n \to +\infty$ we have a contraction.

I don' understand this solution because when $n \to +\infty$ then $S$ changes ,too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for all $n$ you have $T,S \in B$. If $a=\min B$ and $b=\max B$, then you have

$$a \leq T \leq \frac{S^2}{2} - \frac{n}{2}m^2 \leq \frac{b^2}{2} - \frac{n}{2}m^2 \longrightarrow -\infty$$

so you have a contradiction.